# chrome storage: Unable to change component state from a callback function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I'm having issues switching state of a material desing component from an asynchronous callback function.

HTML markup

```
<mat-slide-toggle
      class="example-margin"
      [color]="color"
      [checked]="checked">
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

DOESN'T WORK
I'm sure that the callback function gets context to everything it needs, including "this.checked" variable, but for some reason it's not propagated to the material design component.

```
checked:boolean;

ngOnInit() {
     chrome.storage.local.get('isActive',  (data) => {
         console.log(data); // {isActive:true}
         console.log(this); //context is visible
         this.checked = data.isActive; //true
         console.log(this.checked); //true
     });
}
```

WORKS.
This callback function works OK.

```
checked:boolean;

ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.checked = true;
    }, 5000)
}
```

**NOTE**: There's definitely an issue with rendering. When I click some button, which is totally irelevant to this, this component gets re-rendered correctly.

Comment: Does it still work if you add a timeout value to the working callback?

Comment: Yes, I just forgot to mention it here. It works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you could do is check whether data.isActive is equal to 'checked' and if it isn't, toggle the component so they're consistent. Something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
     chrome.storage.local.get('isActive',  (data) => {
         if (data.isActive != checked){
             this.toggle();
         }
     });
}
```

That should trigger a change event, so that the change is propagated to the view.

Comment: It's basically what I'm doing minus the check. I added the check but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the async call around a Promise and it started to work. Funny thing the Observables (I also tried them) didn't work

Here is a working code

**COMPONENT:**

```
checked:boolean;

constructor(private storageService: StorageService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getStorageData();
}
```

**ASYNC important**

```
async getStorageData(): Promise<any> {
    let storageData = await this.storageService.getStorageData();
    console.log(storageData); //{isActive:true};
    this.checked = value.isActive; //this works!!!
    //if you want you can return a value and access it with then() function in the ngOnInit
}
```

**SERVICE**

```
public getStorageData():Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      chrome.storage.local.get('isActive',  (data) => {
        console.log(data); //data
        resolve(data); {isActive:true}
      });
    });
  }
```

Can anyone explain why Observables don't work while promises do?